# gzip topojson files in terminal but then can't be read in modern browser

Tags: gzip, leaflet, topojson

Building an online interactive map with leaflet and some heavy layers with my spatial data in topojson format. I have been reading about gzip but I am still uncertain how to configure it.

Do I need to:

gzip the files used for my leaflet map myself in my terminal ?
change my javascript code so that instead of calling 1966.topojson I call 1966.topojson.gz ?
change the apache server (2nd generation) in some way? Not sure how to change it so that it can send topojson files. Is there any good tutorial around for that?
Thanks

Here is a 
[link](http://140.112.64.66/website/taiwancensus/#legend)

Comment: Please share a link or fiddle at least. Thanks.

Comment: You should first of all improve the speed =), does not really finish loadings for me.